# How do I summarize and group by various key data contained in multiple mySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache

I want to track how my users progress through their lifecycle on my site into exclusive states like:

```
registered
updated profile
first post
etc.
```

While the state will always be exclusive - meaning one particular state at a time - the user may also belong to various groups and subgroups such as:

```
Group       Subgroup
Referred    Search
Referred    Email
Engineer    Software
Engineer    Hardware
```

I plan to log these state changes into a mySQL table, updating a unique row per user accordingly:

```
user_lifecycle tbl
---------------------
user_id (pk)
join_date
state
```

And I’m thinking that the Groups should be stored in another table since the user can belong to many at the same time:

```
user_groupings tbl
-------------------------
grouping_id (auto-counter - pk)
user_id
group
subgroup
```

To provide proper charting (for cohort analysis) using a 3rd party tool, I need to query and export to the following summarized format (which will need to be converted to CSV)

```
Group,Subgroup,Joined,Registered,Updated Profile,First Post
Referred,Search,10/25/12,5,5,5
Referred,Search,10/26/12,10,10,0
Referred,Email,10/25/12 5,5,5
Referred,Email,10/26/12 5,0,5
Engineer,Software,10/25/12,0,5,10
Engineer,Software,10/26/12,15,5,0
Engineer,Hardware,10/25/12,10,5,0
Engineer,Hardware,10/26/12,5,5,5
Total,,10/25/12,10,10,10
Total,,10/26/12,20,10,5
```

Is my table structure appropriate for this?  If so, how might I query to provide the desired result?  If not, what would you change and what would be the corresponding query?  if it helps, I also will be using PHP server side.  I’m thinking this might work:

```
SELECT join_date AS Date, SUM(IF(state = ‘registered’, 1, 0)) AS 'Registered', SUM(IF(state = ‘updated profile’, 1, 0)) AS 'Updated Profile', SUM(IF(state = ‘first post’, 1, 0)) AS 'First Post'
FROM user_lifecycle
GROUP BY join_date
```

but I’m not sure how to properly add the other table and add the other groupings.

Comment: you know you can do this with google analytics

Comment: As I understand it, google analytics cannot perform cohort analysis without hacks, but I'd be interested to hear what you know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the groupings table should be a join table, and group would have a self reference as well. For example:

```
groups
--------
id
name
parent_id (fk to groups)

user_groups
------------
id (auto-counter - pk)
user_id
group_id
```

This way you can assign a user to a group and a group can have multiple subgroups. However if you want to support subgroups down to multiple levels (ie. a subgroup can have subgroups) then you'll want to look into nested set implementations.